# How do I send a message to a WSO2 Message Broker from a Node.js client

Tags: node.js, wso2

Does anyone know how to send a message to a WSO2 Message Broker from a client written in Node.js?

Answer (score 3):

As WSO2 Message Broker supports AMQP protocol you should be able to do this with any NodeJS AMQP 0-9-1 Client Library. Some of the examples are,

1. amqp.node : https://github.com/squaremo/amqp.node
2. node-amqp : https://github.com/postwait/node-amqp

The following sample code, written using amqp.node library can be used as a NodeJS client to publish or receive messages from WSO2 Message Broker. You have to use the format `amqp://{username}:{password}@{hostname}:{port}` to establish a connection with Message Broker. All messages will be sent as byte messages but can be received as text.

'amqp.node' library provide a rich [API](https://github.com/squaremo/amqp.node) which can be used to other Queue operations MB too.

```
// Sample Publisher
var queuename = 'MyQueue';
var openConn = require('amqplib').connect('amqp://admin:admin@localhost:5672'); // amqp://{username}:{password}@{hostname}:{port} is default AMQP connection URL of WSO2 MB
openConn.then(function(conn) {
  var ok = conn.createChannel();
  ok = ok.then(function(channel) {
    channel.assertQueue(queuename);
    channel.sendToQueue(queuename, new Buffer('New Message'));
  });
  return ok;
}).then(null, console.warn);
```

The consumer client code is as follows.

```
// Sample Consumer
var queuename = 'MyQueue';
var openConn = require('amqplib').connect('amqp://admin:admin@localhost:5672'); // amqp://{username}:{password}@{hostname}:{port} is default AMQP connection URL of WSO2 MB
openConn.then(function(conn) {
  var ok = conn.createChannel();
  ok = ok.then(function(channel) {
    channel.assertQueue(queuename);
    channel.consume(queuename, function(msg) {
      console.log(msg.content.toString());
      channel.ack(msg);
    });
  });
  return ok;
}).then(null, console.warn);
```

Answer (score 0):

[WSO2 Message Broker](http://wso2.com/products/message-broker/) supports Advanced Message Queuing Protocol (AMQP) v0.91.

I haven't tried this myself, but you should be able to use a Node.js client to connect with WSO2 MB.

See [amqp.node](https://github.com/squaremo/amqp.node) project at GitHub.

You can connect with WSO2 MB using the AMQP connection URL. See the "[Sending and Receiving Messages Using Queues](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/MB210/Sending+and+Receiving+Messages+Using+Queues)" doc to understand how AMQP connection URL can be specified to connect with WSO2 MB.

I hope this helps!

Thanks!